# Finding the equation of a circle and hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry

[image]             [image]

The two graphs above are the graphs of functions $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $y=\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

How do you figure out the equations of the corresponding circle and hyperbola?

Comment: If you mean the equation of the entire aforementioned circle and hyperbola, you just square both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring either equation gives you what you want: $y^2=1-x^2$ for the circle, and $y^2=1+x^2$ for the hyperbola.  Rearrange either any way you want.